# Show "loading layout" while sending requests

Tags: android

I have activity and when it is created it sends some requests, so it takes time to load this activity.
Is it possible to show "loading layout" while requests are proceeding?
I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
setContentView(R.layout.loading);

sendRequests();

setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: You can send requests after your view is inflated or send the requests in background via a Thread/Coroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, you could add a "loading layout" to your main layout.

Something like this:

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Loading stuff" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then when it is time to show your loading layout you can do:

```java
FrameLayout loadingLayout = findViewById(R.id.loading_layout);
loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

When you want to hide it simply:

```java
loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You will want to make sure that you do network requests off of the main thread, and return to the main thread whenever it is time to update the UI (i.e. show/hide the loading layout).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a progress bar in activity or fragment.

If you are using Retrofit or etc., use this approach:

Set the progressbar visible before request
and invisible it when **onResponse** or **onFailure**  called

```
binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // request
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse is called");

            // invisible progress bar here
            binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (!response.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "No Success");
            }
            mMovieList = response.body().getMovies();  // <- response is null here
            mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure is called");

            // invisible progress bar here
            binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create common class for custom progress dialog,

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends Dialog {
    
        public CustomProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
        }
    
        public CustomProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context, int themeResId) {
            super(context, themeResId);
            init(context);
        }
    
        protected CustomProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context, boolean cancelable, @Nullable OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
            super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
            init(context);
        }
    
        void init(Context context) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            getWindow().setDimAmount(0.1f);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((v, insets) -> {
                insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
                return insets;
            });
    
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.dialog_custom, null
            );
            setContentView(view);
            setCancelable(false);
            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }
    }
```

dialog_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Declare this class in your activity or parent activity to use in every child classes,

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    protected CustomProgressDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDialog = new CustomProgressDialog(requireActivity());
    }
}
```

To show dialog before your api call

```
mDialog.show();
```

To dismiss dialog in response or error

```
mDialog.dismiss();
```